# Fluent UI React - Date Picker Validation styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fluentvalidation, fluent

I want to add validation to my date picker, as shown in the image below. It is a field inside a form. I want to validate on submit button click. I can write the custom logic to validate the field, but i want to show validation alert if value is not given as shown in the image.

Please help me on this

[image]

I added a date picker from fluent UI react V9 using the below code.

const [mydate, setMydate] = useState(null)

const onFormatDate = (date) => {
return !date
? ""
: (date.getMonth() + 1) +
"/" +
date.getDate() +
"/" +
(date.getFullYear());
};

Please see the below link for more information

https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/compat-components-datepicker--default#required